# Uploading files to an FTP server

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, ftp, c#-3.0, ftpwebrequest

The purpose of my application is, it has to uploade files to a FTP server, and then move the local files to an Archive folder. Here is my code:

```
public void UploadLocalFiles(string folderName)
        {
            try
            {

                string localPath = @"\\Mobileconnect\filedrop_to_ssis\" + folderName;
                string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(localPath);

                foreach (string filepath in files)
                {
                    string fileName = Path.GetFileName(filepath);
                    localFileNames = files;
                    reqFTP = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(new Uri("ftp:...../inbox/" + fileName));
                    reqFTP.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
                    reqFTP.UsePassive = true;
                    reqFTP.UseBinary = true;
                    reqFTP.ServicePoint.ConnectionLimit = files.Length;
                    reqFTP.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password");
                    reqFTP.EnableSsl = true;
                    ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = Certificate;

                    FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(localPath + @"\" + fileName);
                    byte[] fileContents = new byte[fileInfo.Length];

                    FileStream fileStream = fileInfo.OpenRead();

                    fileStream.Read(fileContents, 0, Convert.ToInt32(fileInfo.Length));


                    Stream writer = reqFTP.GetRequestStream();

                    writer.Write(fileContents, 0, fileContents.Length);
                }

                reqFTP.Abort();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error in GetLocalFileList method!!!!!" + e.Message);
            }

        }
```

After runing this method, i cant move the files, i get this exception message : "Cant access file, the file is being used by another process". It is my Filestream or Stream that is locking my files. When i surround Filestream and Stream by `using` it doesn't uploade the files to the  FTP as it does wihtout `using`. I cant see why, can anyone help with this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in filestream, that you are using to read files.

You need to close it.

Just add `fileStream.Close()` just **before end** of foreach loop.

Comment: Thank you for the tip. It worked finally. I thought it was my Stream that was locking the file. But ofcourse it was the Filestream because it has access to the local file.

Answer (score 1):

Try using [FileStream.Dispose](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream.dispose.aspx) after you're done. This should have the same effect as 'using'.

Comment: i have tried that, but tried it again, and it didnt' help. I get the same Exception. **IOException: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process**

Comment: I think you're not supposed to use FtpWebRequest.Abort, instead you should use Close, like here http://blog.logiclabz.com/c/ftp-file-upload-using-ftpwebrequest-in-net-c.aspx

Comment: In that example, he is not closing the **FtpWebRequest** bust the **FileStream** and the **Stream**

Comment: you're right, sorry about that. My point is: the above mentioned sample should work. Try to modify the code to match it.

Comment: Ive tried modifying this code, many times. The Stream uploads the file, but as soon as i use the `Writer.Close()` or `using` the file is deleted from the FTP server. but cant i just use `Writer.Flush()` insted ??